# What is the actual CUDA version when nvcc states 9.1 and nvidia-smi states 10.1?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

Installed CUDA. Intended to install v10.1.

When checking version of it, nvcc output claims that the version is 9.1:

```
sk@sk-desktop:~$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

However when check using nvidia-smi:

```
sk@sk-desktop:~$ nvidia-smi
Fri Nov  8 15:11:53 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.50       Driver Version: 430.50       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
```

...

So what causes this difference and which version have I installed? Is it possible that both versions of CUDA are coexisting?